# Would a jetty sdkman candidate be worthwhile?

Tags: jetty, sdkman

I use sdkman to install JDKs and maven, but I see that tomcat is also offered as a candidate.  Do developers often use sdkman to install a servlet / HTTP server?   Would there be any interest in a Jetty candidate?